# Angular project not displaying on browser

Tags: angular

My app was working fine before until a moment, the browser page just went blank. If I refresh the page, nothing will show and I tried updating the cli and I tried the `ng serve` command several times. it keep showing compile successfully but nothing on the browser.

> Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
> : Compiled successfully

I viewed the page source but shows nothing and
I inspect the browser page and in the console, It shows this error:

```
<pre>
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[AngularFireAuth -> AngularFireAuth -> AngularFireAuth]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularFireAuth!
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:18071:27)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:32065:33)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:32065:33)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:32065:33)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:49366:33)
    at Object.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:47100:35)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:21873:39)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:35880:12)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.AppComponent_Factory [as factory] (http://localhost:4200/main.js:943:409)
    at getNodeInjectable (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:22018:44)
</pre>
```

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: "No provider for AngularFireAuth" is a fairly straight forward and common error message. Have you added it to your app module and imported it?

Answer (score 0):

I actually find a way through, thanks. I found out I was importing `AngularFireAuth` from both `@angular/fire/auth` and `angularfire2/auth`. I was mixing them together hence the error, that was what I understood from the problem, It's working now. If anyone could elaborate more on what else might be the issue.
Thanks